# Where to ask questions about hardware / wireless connection?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I want to connect two houses with a low network latency. On which SX site to ask this question?

Answer (score 5):

I think [www.SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/) is better place.

[It's FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)

Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

- computer hardware
- computer software
- personal and home computer networking