# Which community to ask about 4G connection issues

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm trying to track down why my 4G dongle internet connection keeps 'hanging' (device says there is a solid connection but I can't access the internet until I reboot, this happens with 2 MiFi devices and 2 different SIMs from the same provider).

The stuff I *think* I've eliminated as causes means I'm left in unfamiliar territory. Recommendations for potential SE sites to look at?

edit: I don't see this as a dupe of the linked question. That talks about setting up a wireless network, not about mobile internet. And the answer recommends a site about home computing - this is a question about mobile devices not PCs. I'm pretty sure I would get my question closed on SuperUser.

Comment: android comes up most commonly but this isn't an Android-specific issue (I've no idea what technology my MiFi dongles run on)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to ask questions about hardware / wireless connection?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155132/where-to-ask-questions-about-hardware-wireless-connection)

Comment: @nicael I think they're quite different topics (I've edited to explain) and the site recommended there is about computers not mobile tech

Comment: I think nicael is right - mobile tech is still all about computers

Comment: Mobile internet is still networking, per the tour: "Specific issues with computer software, hardware or **networking**".

Comment: That reads "computer networking", not computers and networking. I can try there but as a fairly active member it is more focused on computers, not mobile phones and the like. Since my question (appears to be) about what happens between the SIM and the carrier, that would suggest it's out of scope... we'll see!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not a home on a Stack Exchange site for every question. It's quite possible that there _isn't_ a place in Stack Exchange where that would be an on-topic question.